# Application_Start Vs Session_Start

Tags: asp.net, webforms, session-state, application-start, application-state

Actually I am new to ASP.NET and I came through these concepts. 
What is the difference between `Application_Start` Vs `Session_Start`?

And also how to know how many users are currently active in our application? Is by using `Application_Start` or by using `Session_Start`?

Comment: Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Application_Start executes just once when the application/worker process starts or IIS restarts. You can instantiate application variables, for example.

Session_start executes each time a Session is created, such as to instantiate and manage visitor data.

Answer (score 0):

Application_Start Method is Fired on When the Application Started
Application_Start runs once before Files are Processed

Where

Session_Start Method is Fired at the beginning of each session.
Session_Start runs at the starts of each unique user session.